# How do I convert this ARM Concat string to Terraform Concat please

Tags: string, azure-devops, terraform, azure-resource-manager, terraform-provider-azure

Ive been trying for a few hours now to work out how to convert this ARM Concat String to a Terraform Concat String.

```
"[Concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('accountName'), ';AccountKey=', parameters('accountKey'), ';EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net')]"
```

Terraform what I have so far

```
value = Concat(['DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', parameters('azurerm_storage_account.website_storage_account')], [';AccountKey=', parameters('zurerm_storage_account.website_storage_account.primary_access_key'),] ';EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net')]"
```

Also tried

```
format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https"";"""AccountName="%s{azurerm_storage_account.website_storage_account}";""""AccountKey="%s{azurerm_storage_account.website_storage_account.primary_access_key}";"EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net")
```

What I am trying to achieve is to put these two values: `azurerm_storage_account.website_storage_account` & `azurerm_storage_account.website_storage_account.primary_access_key` in their right places within this string:

`DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={acountName};AccountKey={accountKey};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net`

Comment: A big part of the problem is that your Terraform attempt is trying to use ARM syntax. Variables in Terraform are not accessed the same way as ARM parameters. Refer to the Terraform documentation.

Comment: I did reason for following the format and concat string. Also you can specify a variable in terraform with ${}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies if I missing something but I think this is simpler than it first appears.

```
value = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${azurerm_storage_account.website_storage_account.name};AccountKey=${azurerm_storage_account.website_storage_account.primary_access_key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
```

Within a string contained within `""`, Terraform resource attributes can be interpolated within `${}`.

I have also modified `azurerm_storage_account.website_storage_account` to `azurerm_storage_account.website_storage_account.name` as you have to specify an attribute of the resource, rather than just the resource. I took a guess that `name` is what you required here, but you can look at the alternative attributes [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/storage_account)

Comment: I did that and Terraform didn’t like it. Didn’t pass terraform validate.

Comment: What was the actual validation error - everything else being equal, that should work?

Comment: It didn’t like the ; that’s what throw me off.

Comment: Terraform errors can be misleading. I can't see a reason why a semi-colon would be significant. Did you definitely have an attribute in the resource you specified for '{accountName}', cos in your examples you don't as I mentioned in my note at the bottom. That would cause an error if missing.

Comment: I’ll try your solution today and if it gives me an error I’ll post it in. Maybe I haven’t put in the “ in the right places. Thanks.

Comment: So your solution did work but I had to wrap it in a format string so it looks like this now: format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=${azurerm_storage_account.website_storage_account.name};AccountKey=${azurerm_storage_account.website_storage_account.primary_access_key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net") 

Thanks :)